# How to Serialize a list after using SGEN

Tags: list, xmlserializer, sgen

How can I serialize a list when using SGEN generated assembly?

After generating the assembly I have access to classes such as: PersonSerilizer and can serialize one object, but how can I Serialize a list of this objects?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I created classes that has only one property as a list of the serialized classes.

Maybe it's not the best but it works fine.